# How to convert to_timestamp in H2?

Tags: oracle, h2

I am trying to convert the following Oracle date type into its equivalent H2 date type

```sql
to_timestamp('26-APR-23 10.38.27.666000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM').
```

Tried with a few `PARSEDATETIME()` options, but nothing is working.

```
Unable to parse the oracle to_timestamp format to its equivalent format in H2
```

Answer (score 0):

H2 supports Oracle-style `TO_TIMPSTAMP` function only in Oracle and PostgreSQL compatibility modes.

To enable the Oracle compatibility mode you need to append `;MODE=Oracle;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` to JDBC URL.

To enable the PostgreSQL compatibility mode you need to append `;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` to JDBC URL.

---

H2's own `PARSEDATETIME` is availiable in all compatibility modes, but it currently (in H2 2.1.214) performs case-sensitive parsing, it can parse `Apr`, but cannot parse `APR` as April.

```sql
VALUES PARSEDATETIME('26-Apr-23 10.38.27.666000000 PM',
    'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss[.nnnnnnnnn] a', 'EN');
```

Comment: I am using H2 1.2.147  version, I tried the above format but still getting the following expectation Error parsing "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss[.nnnnnnnnn] a/EN/null";

Comment: You're using a 13-years-old unsupported version of H2, it is very different from modern versions and cannot parse such values. You need to upgrade it, but if you cannot do it for a some reason, you can create an own user-defined function.